# How to get cities list of each state of United States in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

There are 51 states in United States.
And each state takes many cities.
I want to get the cities list of each state.
so i just tried as followings.

Used libraries:

- [country-state-city](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city)
- [usa-states](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usa-states)

```sh
npm install country-state-city
npm install usa-states
```

```js
import { UsaStates } from 'usa-states';
import csc from 'country-state-city';

const usStates = new UsaStates();
const states = usStates.states.map((state) => state.name);
const cities = csc.getCitiesOfCountry(states[0]);
```

But no results of variable `cities`.

Comment: **"There are 51 states in United States"** - the fact you didn't even get that basic fact of geopolitics correct does not fill me with confidence about the rest of your abilities...

Comment: Please, don't paste images which can be substituted with text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What `But no results` means? You don't `console.log` it out, you are not reporting any error. Also, you could help a bit your helpers (us) by posting the library docs, where we (and you) could read its API documentation.

Comment: Where does `csc` comes from?

Comment: @Dai Politics of USA != geopolitics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is correct answer.**

At first, please install proper module.

```
npm install country-state-city
```

Full code:

```
import csc from 'country-state-city';

const countryCode = 'US';
const country = csc.getCountryByCode(countryCode);
const states = csc.getStatesOfCountry(country.isoCode);
states.forEach((state) => {
    cities_of_state = csc.getCitiesOfState(countryCode, state.isoCode)
    console.log(state, ":", cities_of_state)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use `csc.getCitiesOfState(countryCode, stateCode)` instead of `csc.getCitiesOfCountry`. Also, you don't need `usa-states` package:

```js
const countryCode = 'US';
const country = csc.getCountryByCode(countryCode);
const states = csc.getStatesOfCountry(country.isoCode);
const citiesFromFirstState = csc.getCitiesOfState(countryCode, states[0].isoCode);

console.log("Cities:", {
  state: states[0],
  cities: citiesFromFirstState,
});
```

**Note:** Take a look into it's [test suite](https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city/blob/master/__test__/index.test.ts).

Answer (score 0):

```
  const Country = require('country-state-city').Country
  const State = require('country-state-city').State
  const City = require('country-state-city').City


  const countryCode = 'IN';
  const country = Country.getCountryByCode(countryCode);
  const states = State.getStatesOfCountry(countryCode);
  const stateCode = 'BR';
  const cities = City.getCitiesOfState(countryCode, stateCode)
  console.log(states ) //print all states of country
  console.log(cities) //print all cities of state
```